# Why is the request.protocol always http instead of https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, http-post

I have this page that does a POST request:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://staging.cathytest.com/user/signup">
    <input name="data" value="tsd213guHUUDUhyusgd4314yDTSgts435dfsg" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then the controller action `signup` will check if the request protocol is https. I get the protocol using `request.protocol`, but it always gives me http. Can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: I guess it's because your reverse proxy offloaded https, but I can't be sure without the configuration of the reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.force_ssl = true
  end
end
```

This will force rails to use https for all requests.

Comment: Is there another way? Because the request is from another API. I just need to determine in the controller whether they sent me an https or http request protocol.

Comment: You can do this at the Rack level with the rack-ssl-enforcer gem. It's configurable to allow exclusion of specific paths, hosts, and methods. If it meets your needs, I'd recommend doing this over rolling your own solution.